# Cannot download Beta by Crashlytics from invitation email

Tags: crashlytics, fastlane, google-fabric, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

I deployed android app using Beta by Crashlytics and sent invitation to a user, the user opened the invitation in his android device and saw the following message:

"Open the invitation email on your device to begin registering for beta testing"

and not the Download button that will allow him to install Beta app as expected.

I deployed the app using Fastlane, not sure if it's related.

Any idea what could be the reason ?

Answer (score 3):

I reproduced this on 2 different devices, and this appears to be an issue with the user agent reported by the browser that services the link [1].

Fix: Install chrome if absent. Alternately, copy the link at the top of the opened invitation and paste it into chrome.

[1] https://github.com/webcompat/web-bugs/issues/3896

Comment: It was relevant to me (hence my question upvote). If you're able to confirm that my answer does indeed address the original question, that could prove useful for others. If you had a different problem not addressed by this answer, that could also help others.

Comment: As you can see this issue is from few months ago, I don't even remember which app it was and for which user :)

Comment: Faced the very same issue on iPad today. The linked issue on github helped. Apple now makes Safari on iPad work in desktop mode by default. Switching to mobile solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the tester hasn't accepted the invitation to test your app yet. Check out https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/beta-walkthrough.html to view the Beta steps and emails that testers receive. Once the tester accepts the invitation they can download builds.

Comment: well, the tester already accepted the invitation but on another device, he has now a new device so it seems that this situation is related to using new device.